# Normalization image rgb

Tags: image-processing, processing, normalization, quantization

I have a problem with normalization.
Let me what the problem is and how I attempt to solve it.
I take a three-channel color image, convert it to grayscale and apply uniform or non-uniform quantization and the same thing.
To this image, I should apply the normalization, but I have a problem even if the image and grayscale and always has three channels.
How can I apply normalization having a three-channel image?
Should the min and the max all be in the three channels?
Could someone give me a hand?
The language I am using is processing 2.

P.S.
Can you do the same thing with a color image instead use a grayscale image?

Comment: I'd recommend normalizing in gray scale because the 3-channels are not given equal weights in terms of gray intensity.  For example, an rgb of (.5, .5, .5) doesn't necessarily have a grayscale of 128 (out of 256).

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply, the problem with processing that you can not have one channel that I know of.

Comment: Check out my answer in response.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert between the 1-channel and 3-channel representations easily.  I'd recommend scikit-image (http://scikit-image.org/).

```
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.color import rgb2gray, gray2rgb

rgb_img = imread('path/to/my/image')
gray_img = rgb2gray(rgb_image)

# Now normalize gray image
gray_norm = gray_img / max(gray_img)

# Now convert back
rgb_norm = gray2rgb(gray_norm)
```

Comment: Thank you your answers, but I would like to apply the normalization of a color image. But I have no idea how to do. xD

Answer (score 0):

I worked with a similar problem sometime back. One of the good solutions to this was to:

- Convert the image from RGB to HSI
- Leaving the Hue and Saturation channels unchanged, simply normalize across the Intensity channel
- Convert back to RGB

This logic can be applied accross several other image processing tasks, like for example, applying histogram equalization to RGB images.